# organisation tag should be organization

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-naming, tagging

As noted here [British English vs. American English in tags](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/british-english-vs-american-english-in-tags), we generally leave questions in the language variant in which they were asked, but tags are standardi***z***ed as American English. That means that [organisation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organisation) really should be renamed to [organization](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organization).

Comment: Done. The tag has been created and merged.

Comment: Man, Joanne, you are so on the ball I've almost forgotten a ball exists...! :P

Comment: @jrista - So do you only remember one ball then?

Comment: @jrista LOL, timing is everything I guess, it popped up just as I logged on.