# Create Tag Analogue

Tags: discussion, tags

I have too little rep (188) to create own tags.
Is there a reason why there is no tag for "analgoue"?
The standard is probably digital these days so I think it could be good to have one for analogue which is rarer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In photography, the term of art for that is *film*, which of course we have a tag for: [film](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film).

Comment: well - I was trying to add the tag "analogue" to a question which is about an analogue camera, not about the film itself.
The question had nothing to do with the film at all. Would you still advise to use the tag film?

Comment: @bweber I would recommend still using the [tag:film] tag. If you look at the [tags](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags) page, and narrow it down to 'film' in the `Type to find:` box, you'll see that [tag:film] is far and away the main subject, in terms of number of questions, for photography dealing with film. You could use [tag:film-cameras], but there's only 4 questions under that tag.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I am happy to accept this answer. It won´t let me upvote it though - "unless this answer is editet".

Comment: @bweber no worries. Votes on the meta site don't affect rep, and tend to be more of a "agree"/"disagree" thing. Happy to help! =)

Comment: @bweber - a camera is always "analog" as it simply is a conduit for light and a gate to control how much you let in.  Either you capture with film or a digital sensor, otherwise the cameras aren't really inherently different.  Some of the controls may use digital or analog sensors, but that is a mix and match and some film cameras had digital metering or AF, so it still doesn't really have much purpose outside of other more specific tags.

Answer (score 4):

First, see [British English vs. American English in tags](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/british-english-vs-american-english-in-tags) — we've standardized on American English spelling for tags for consistency (but, we leave whatever variant the writer uses in titles, questions, and answers). So, it would be [analog](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analog).

*However*, "analog camera" is a retronym. Until digital cameras came along, there was no word for such a thing — they were just *cameras*. So, while analog (or "analogue")  might be an okay label, I don't think it's a *universal* one.

This is compounded by the fact that the sensors used in digital cameras are *analog devices* — it just happens that we digitize their output for our convenience. In a slightly-alternate world, we might have that output instead written to tape or some mini-[laserdisc](http://mentalfloss.com/article/49111/mr-wizard-explains-laserdisc). Of course, we aren't in that alternate world, but, still, analog isn't necessarily the *opposite* of "digital camera".

Plus, there are many things other than camera recording medium which are "analog" — some light meters, for example. A tag grouping all of those things isn't necessarily particularly useful.

All that said, I think what you're looking for is **[film-cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film-cameras)**.